# SQLAlchemy: Specifying session to use for model

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using Flask-SQLAlchemy and I need to create a session without auto-flushing for an operation. However, the default scoped session that is created by Flask-SQLAlchemy which is accessed using `db.session` has auto-flushing turned on.

I'm doing bulk updates for 100k rows, and the auto-flushing is causing severe performance issues.

I tried creating a new session with auto-flushing turned off using:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SignallingSession
db_session = SignallingSession(db, autoflush=False)
```

And then I tried creating a new row using:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy, BaseQuery

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Tool(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
title = db.Column(db.String(1024), nullable=True)

add_tool = Tool()
add_tool.title = title

db_session.add(add_tool)
```

However, doing this throws the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app", line 182, in <module>
called for last item
    import_tools('x.json', 1)
  File "app", line 173, in import_tools
    x.add_to_database()
  File "app", line 126, in add_to_database
    title=metadata['title'], commit=True)
  File "app", line 150, in transfer
    self.db_session.add(import_tool)
  File ".virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1492, in add
    self._save_or_update_state(state)
  File ".virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1504, in _save_or_update_state
    self._save_or_update_impl(state)
  File ".virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1759, in _save_or_update_impl
    self._save_impl(state)
  File ".virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1731, in _save_impl
    self._attach(state)
  File ".virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1849, in _attach
    state.session_id, self.hash_key))
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Object '<Tool at 0x11361f4d0>' is already attached to session '1' (this is '2')
```

What I believe is happening is that when the object is created, it is attached to the global scoped session that is provided by Flask-SQLAlchemy, while I want it to be attached to the session that I created. I tried looking through the code and documentation for Flask-SQLAlchemy and SQLAlchemy, but I couldn't find either the source of the problem or the solution to it.

Is there some way I can specify which session to use when the object is created using the model class? Or is there something totally different that I am missing which would be causing this problem?

Comment: Instead of using two sessions, you can pass `autoflush=False` to `db = SQLAlchemy(app)`. The SQLAlchemy object takes a `session_options` param: https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/api.html#flask.ext.sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy

Comment: Can the session be flushed after your no flush operations complete?

Comment: @nathancahill the problem is that I want autoflush throughout my app. This is the only operation where I do not want autoflush to be active. Hence why the need for two sessions, unless there is a better way.

Comment: @dirn I'm doing a `db.session.commit()` after the no flush operations complete, which automatically does a `db.session.flush()` first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQLAlchemy sessions provide a [`no_autoflush` context manager](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.no_autoflush). This will suspend any flushes until after you exit the block.

```
model1 = Model(name='spam')
db.session.add(model1)  # This will flush

with db.session.no_autoflush:
    model2 = Model()
    db.session.add(model2)  # This will not

    model2.name = 'eggs'

db.session.commit()
```

Comment: @dirn will the object be created successfully, if some attributes require making http requests? i.e creating a person object and you need to select state meaning a view /states select one then a view /townsinthatstate

Comment: @roy I'm not really sure what an HTTP request has to do with a SQLAlchemy session. If you make the requests in your model's `__init__` and they raise any uncaught exceptions, then no, your objects won't be created successfully. If you catch the exception or make the requests elsewhere, then yes, they will be. None of that has anything to do with SQLAlchemy, though.

Comment: @dirn so I can make http requests (meaning access other views in flask) that finally lead to a foo.bar = form.bar.data but if it raises an error, the object won't be created unless I catch it?

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure what you trying to do. Based on that one line of code, the `foo` object will have already been created; otherwise you wouldn't be able to assign to its `bar` attribute. Whatever it is you're doing, you should ask a new question. Comments aren't a great format for helping you with something unrelated to the original question.